# jQuery-Enter key event function alerts repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have to prevent the form submit if the `newVal` and `oldVal` are equal. Else I need to execute the Javascript function. - While pressing `Enter` key from the key board for the dynamically generated textboxes.

For this case, While pressing enter key the alert is coming repeatedly.
ie, first time one alert. Two alerts for second time.And the expected result is not getting.

What is expected: If I enter a value equals to the `curValue` then form doesn't have to submit.Else need to call the function `myFun();` What is wrong with me?

```
function pressEnter(id,newValue,i)
{
var newId = '#'+id;
$(newId).keydown(function(event) {
var curValue= '<%=currentVal%>';

   var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
    alert(newValue+"-"+curValue);
      if(newValue== curValue)
      {
      event.preventDefault();
      }
      else
      {
      myFun(i);
      }

     }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this comparison on form submit event rather than pressing enter key. Because user can use mouse and click the submit button.

Restrict user on form submit as follows,

```
$("#your_form_id").submit(function() {
var newValue = $(".your_textbox").val();
var curValue= '<%=currentVal%>';
if(newValue== curValue)
{
event.preventDefault();
//Or use return false;
} else{
myFun();
}
});
```

Here, we can avoid unwanted bind and unbind operations.

And we can achieve this on enter press, just write without function as follows,

```
$("#your_text_box_id").keydown(function(event) {
var newValue = $(".your_textbox").val();
var curValue= '<%=currentVal%>';

var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
alert(newValue+"-"+curValue);
if(newValue== curValue)
{
event.preventDefault();
}else{
 myFun();
}
}
});
```

Note: If you scope this jQuery code within a function,then javascript add handler for same event on every function call. Result is your code(Code in "keydown" callback) run multiple time. To avoid you have to unbind the event.

Comment: Sorry, pressing Enter key is my requirement !

Answer (score 4):

You have to unbind previous keydown handler:

```
$(newId).off('keydown').keydown(function(event) {...});
```

Comment: Do I just need to replace my third line of above code to`$(newId).off('keydown').keydown(function(event) {` or I need to unbind separately ? Thanks anyways.

Comment: I dont have all your code like how do you call pressEnter() function, try it and see

Comment: Yea, because I am getting console errors like 'TypeError: $(...).off is not a function'

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using? .off() is for 1.7+ version. Use .unbind() instead if you are using older version.